# Drop down issue in lighting data table

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience

I am not able to set the drop down into right side on action item of lighting data table. Can you please help me anyone to fix this issue. As of now it is moving to left and hiding some part of text.

```
cmp.set('v.PaymentsItemTableColumns', [
            {type: 'action', typeAttributes:{rowActions: [{
                    label: 'Create Payments',                    
                    name:'createPayments',                  
                }
                ]}
            },  
            {label: 'PO Name', fieldName: 'Name', type: 'text'},
            {label: 'Estimated Payment Date', fieldName: 'Estimated_Payment_Date__c', type: 'datetime'},
            {label: 'Payment Amount', fieldName: 'Payment_Amount__c', type: 'currency', typeAttributes: { currencyCode: 'USD'}}
        ]);
```

[image]

Comment: Please edit your question to show the code you're working with.

Comment: Added code Please check

Answer (score 2):

Lightning menus are intended to be used on the rightmost column (see the [SLDS documentation](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/data-tables/)). Move your action column to the rightmost column to comply with SLDS design.

```
cmp.set('v.PaymentsItemTableColumns', [
            {label: 'PO Name', fieldName: 'Name', type: 'text'},
            {label: 'Estimated Payment Date', fieldName: 'Estimated_Payment_Date__c', type: 'datetime'},
            {label: 'Payment Amount', fieldName: 'Payment_Amount__c', type: 'currency', typeAttributes: { currencyCode: 'USD'}},
            {type: 'action', typeAttributes:{rowActions: [{
                    label: 'Create Payments',                    
                    name:'createPayments',                  
                }
                ]}
            }
        ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank You! For your response. I am able to adjust that dropdown menu. Please find the answer below,

```
cmp.set('v.PaymentsItemTableColumns', [
            {label: 'PO Name', fieldName: 'Name', type: 'text'},
            {label: 'Estimated Payment Date', fieldName: 'Estimated_Payment_Date__c', type: 'datetime'},
            {label: 'Payment Amount', fieldName: 'Payment_Amount__c', type: 'currency', typeAttributes: { currencyCode: 'USD'}},
            {type: 'action', typeAttributes:{rowActions: [{
                    label: 'Create Payments',                    
                    name:'createPayments',                  
                }
                ], menuAlignment: 'left'}
            }
        ]);
```

Comment: Hows your answer different from SFDCfox's answer?

Comment: menuAlignment: 'left'            This difference than SFDCfox answer